# Javascript accessing array and displaying its items

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

i have a JSON formatted data here: https://xnia140ixg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Stage1/currencies

And i want to display it in a graph. I wrote that code

```
let CurrData = [];
        let res = axios.get('https://xnia140ixg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Stage1/currencies').then(Response => {
            let data = Response.data.Items
            console.log(data);

            CurrData.push(data);
        });
```

What im trying to do is to push that data into new array that i could access outside this method and then iterate through each of the item. But i cant manage to do that. Thats what im getting now
[image: Array]

What i want to do now is access Price and PriceTimeStamp and put it in plotly.js object, like this:

```
CurrData.forEach(Curr => {
            //Specify how chart should be drawn
            let trace = {
                x: Curr.Price,
                y: Curr.PriceTimeStamp,
                mode: 'line',
                name: Curr.Currency,
                marker: {
                    color: 'rgb(219, 64, 82)',
                    size: 12
                }
            };
```

What should i change?

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
CurrData = data;
```

instead of

```
CurrData.push(data);
```

you're pushing an array into an array.

Answer (score 0):

if youre calling your loop after fetching you're not going to get anything.
Either run inside a setTimeout or async function. Think about your scope. Your calling for data that is still fetching, so Curr is undefined, but if youre in a async function then when you call your loop, it will render when it's done process .

```
async function getData(){
    return await axios.get('https://xnia140ixg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Stage1/currencies').then(Response => {
        return Response.data.Items
    });
}

// is going to work, after it finishes fetching
async function buildTrace(){
    await getData().then(curr => {
        return {
            x: curr['Price'],
            y: curr['PriceTimeStamp'],
            mode: 'line',
            name: curr['Currency'],
            marker: {
                color: 'rgb(219, 64, 82)',
                size: 12
            }
        };
    })
}

// your data is stil fetching, no results == undefined
function buildTrace(){
    await getData().then(curr => {
        return ...
    })
}
```